# PHP function not working

Tags: php, function, boolean, return

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$namecheck  = namecheck($name);

    function namecheck($name){

            if(strlen($name)>0)
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
            else if(strlen($name)==0)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        };

    function control($namecheck1) 
    {
    if ($namecheck == TRUE) 
    {
        echo "It is TRUE"; 
    } 
    else if ($namecheck == FALSE) 
    {
        echo "It is FALSE";
    }
    };
?>
```

I wrote that there is no problem in HTML part, there is a problem in my php functions because I am new in PHP. Can you make it proper.

I think you will understand what I want to do in the functions its simple Im trying to do if it is true I want to see "it is TRUE" in the screen. Else .....

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the variables. They don't match:

```
function control($namecheck1) 
    {
    if ($namecheck == TRUE)
```

You also never actually invoke that function.

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling your 'control' function. try starting with

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$namecheck  = namecheck($name);
control($namecheck);
```

Also, your definition of you function is wrong (or the variable you use is). You can change the function to this

```
 function control($namecheck)
```

Of the if's to

```
if ($namecheck1 == TRUE)
```

in the end the name after `control(` is the one you should check for in the `if`'s

Answer (score 1):

In your `control` function, the parameter is called `$namecheck1` at first, but you only call it `$namecheck` when you try to use it inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you are not calling control function.

Answer (score 1):

your are referencing $namecheck in the function "control" but the parameter passed is named $namecheck1. $namecheck in the scope of function "control" is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

- instead `namecheck()` you can use `empty()`
- before using `$_POST['name']` you should check if it exists `isset()` should help

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];

    function namecheck($name1)
    {

            if(!empty($name1))
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }


    if (namecheck($name) == TRUE) 
    {
        echo "It is TRUE"; 
    } 
    else if (namecheck($name) == FALSE) 
    {
        echo "It is FALSE";
    }

?>
```